# Using get_template_part in WordPress removes my footer

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the contents of another page (page-fixtures.php) to the main page of my site. I have this code -

```
<!-- Fixtures -->
<section class="fixture-page">
     <?php get_template_part( 'page-fixtures' ); ?>
</section>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

I've also tried with `<?php include ?>`

The website shows the contents of that page fine, but my footer disappears. Anyone know why?

Comment: Is `WP_DEBUG` set to `true` in your `wp-config.php` file? That could help determine what is going on here.

Comment: It is set to true but I don't see any errors on the page. My footer does not appear when I use that code

Comment: My guess is that there is some error that is being suppressed that is breaking the page. If you try to show another template part I'm guessing it works. It only happens with that one template part?

Comment: I agree with @TimHerbert. Could you post the contents of `page-fixtures` as well? that may help.

Comment: Just posted it in an answer

Comment: Looking at the code you posted it looks like you are already calling `get_footer()` in the template part. Is this intentional?

Comment: That was the mistake! I removed it and the footer appears again. Thanks